# How to pass C++ object to NPAPI plugin?

Tags: c++, windows, chromium, npapi, chromium-embedded

I'm writing an NPAPI plugin in C++ on Windows.  When my plugin's instantiated, I want to pass it some private data from my main application (specifically, I want to pass it a pointer to a C++ object).  There doesn't seem to be a mechanism to do this.  Am I missing something?  I can't simply create my object in the plugin instance, since it's meant to exist outside of the scope of the plugin instance and persists even when the plugin instance is destroyed.

**Edit:**

I'm using an embedded plugin in C++ via CEF.  This means that my code is essentially the browser and the plugin.  Obviously, this isn't the way standard NPAPI plugins behave, so this is probably not something that's supported by NPAPI itself.

Comment: What do you mean your "main application". Are you saying you want to pass an object from some completely separate application that's already running over to a plugin instance? If so, there's nothing NPAPI-specific about your question, so you'd probably have better lucking asking a new, more general question about how to do IPC on Windows (without mentioning NPAPI).

Comment: Actually, from your comments below it sounds like maybe you are using NPAPI as a plugin interface in your own app, and not writing a browser plugin. NPAPI is intended as a browser plugin interface, so if you aren't writing a browser plugin your problem is that you are using the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: Right, sorry for the confusion.  See the edit to my question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this via NPAPI, since the concept doesn't make sense in NPAPI terms. Even if you hack something up that passes a raw pointer around, that assumes everything is running in one process, so if CEF switches to the multi-process approach Chromium is designed around, the hack would break.

You would be better off pretending they are different processes, and using some non-NPAPI method of sharing what you need to between the main application and the plugin.

Answer (score 2):

You can't pass a C++ object to javascript; what you can do is pass an NPObject that is also a C++ object and exposes things through the NPRuntime interface.

See http://npapi.com/tutorial3 for more information.

You may also want to look at the [FireBreath](http://www.firebreath.org) framework, which greatly simplifies things like this.

**Edit**: it seems I misunderstood your question. What you want is to be able to store data linked to a plugin instance.  What you need is the NPP that is given to you when your plugin is created; the NPP has two members, ndata (netscape data) and pdata (plugin data).  The pdata pointer is yours to control -- you can set it to point to any arbitrary value that you want, and then cast it back to the real type whenever you want to use it.  Be sure to cast it back and delete it on NPP_Destroy, of course.  I usually create a struct to keep a few pieces of information in it.  FireBreath uses this and sends all plugin calls into a Plugin object instance so that you can act as though it were a normal object.

Relevant code example from FireBreath:
https://github.com/firebreath/FireBreath/blob/master/src/NpapiCore/NpapiPluginModule_NPP.cpp#L145

Pay particular attention to NPP_New and NPP_Destroy; also pay particular attention to how the pdata member of the NPP is used.

This is also discussed in http://npapi.com/tutorial2

Comment: I'm not trying to pass a C++ object to JavaScript; I'm trying to pass a pointer to a C++ object to my plugin, so that it's accessible within the NPAPI interface on the C++ side (for example, I would like to access it in NPP_SetWindow and related functions, if possible).  It seems strange to me that there's no (obvious?) way to pass private data to my NPAPI plugin.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood; I have revised my answer to hopefully better answer your question. A suggestion, if I may: don't vote things down until you give people a chance to revise their answer if they just misunderstood you. You may annoy them enough that they won't bother answering. Also, if you had followed the tutorial link and looked around, you would have found the answer to my question on tutorial2; granted that's a lot of reading. I still would recommend looking at FireBreath rather than doing this by hand.

Comment: In the example you posted (NpapiPluginModule_NPP.cpp), NpapiDataHolder is instantiated in NPP_New and associated with pdata.  That much I understood, but my issue is that I want to associate an object with pdata that was created _before_ the plugin instance was instantiated.  In other words, I was hoping there was some mechanism available that would allow me to pass my own data pointer to NPP_New.  I'm starting to think that the only way for me to go about this would be to use SetWindowLongPtr to associate my data pointer with a window handle; I could then fetch that pointer in NPP_SetWindow.

Comment: (BTW, I appreciate your responses and I apologize if my original question was unclear.  It's kind of difficult to explain clearly.  :-)

Comment: I'm not sure how you could have a plugin instance-specific object before NPP_New is called; the browser calls NPP_New, and there is nothing you can do to alter how that is called.  There is nothing stopping you from having a global object somewhere that you can access from your plugin instance, however, or having a global map to map some id (that you could pass in from javascript, etc) to an object instance; I guess I really don't understand your question. Drop into npapi.com/chat sometime and I'll see if I can help better. I'm GMT -0600 and on usually during daylight weekdays, some weekend

Comment: I'm using an embedded plugin instantiated in C++ via CEF (Chromium Embedded Framework).  Sorry, I should have mentioned that in my initial question; it didn't occur to me that it was relevant, but it obviously is.